# Necesito ayuda con una petición. Me devuelve un Json con caracteres raros

Tags: c#, json, http

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{                    
   var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/json/MercadosGet.html?tipo=monedas&id=All");                      
}
```

probé de varias formas y no hay caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es por que no has establecido la descomprension del request a GZip.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/json/MercadosGet.html?tipo=monedas&id=All";

    //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Presta atencion a la siguiente linea de codigo, esta es la importante para tu caso:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Si te fijas tambien deje estas dos lineas comentadas, por si mas adelante las necesitas:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
```

***Mas informacion:***
- [AutomaticDecompression](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [SecurityProtocol](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.7.2)